# How to implement Negation Features in SVM classification (NLP) using imdb Movie_Reviews corpus

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk, svm

I am trying to understand Negation feature in NLP , so I thought to implement it.
I am working on imdb movie review dataset.
Consider I am having data as follows-

```
Movie was great but it's overly sentimental and at times terribly mushy , not to mention very manipulative but great action
```

From the above I can extract **it's overly sentimental and at times terribly mushy** as negative statement and now I am left with these choices-

- I extract the particular line till it ends with some punctuation and
  I simply remove this line from the positive statement and run SVM classifier in
  the rest of the content.
- I extract the particular line and label the line with negative and
  add it to the list of negative statements to train the same.

I am not sure that I am doing anything right here , so please suggest exactly how should I deal with negation features to improvise the classification.

I am working with scikit-learn svm.SVC() classifier

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [NRC Sentiment Analysis](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~saif/WebPages/Abstracts/NRC-SentimentAnalysis.htm) system for text classification using negation. It's very well explained. Also they claim their [SemEval 2014 submission](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/S14-2077) has major improvements on negation handling (I still haven't read it).

I assume you're solving a similar task on movie reviews so this must be what you're looking for.